# Failed Visual Studio 2015 installation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, failed-installation

I tried to install Visual studio 2015 express for Windows 10 on my windows 10 but it failed and didn't install.

Here is a picture:
[image: http://imgur.com/qWY56qD]

I tried uninstalling and installing again but it didn't work.

Here is [the log file](http://www.filedropper.com/ddwinexpressfull20150805180452127winexpresscoremsi).

This looks like the section causing the issue:

```
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:658]: SECREPAIR: A general error running CryptAcquireContext
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:658]: Determining source type
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:659]: Source type from package 'winexpress_coremsi.msi': 0
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:659]: SECREPAIR: Hash Database: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\SourceHash{4D2824C5-DA58-3442-BB90-F71EA6B07EA9}
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:661]: Note: 1: 2262 2: SourceHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:705]: SECREPAIR: New Hash Database creation complete.
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:705]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:0
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:714]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:0
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:714]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:0
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:714]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:0
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:714]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:0
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:714]: SECREPAIR: Crypt Provider not initialized. Error:997
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:714]: SECUREREPAIR: Failed to CreateContentHash of the file: cab5.cab: for computing its hash. Error: 997
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:717]: SECREPAIR: Failed to create hash for the install source files
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:717]: SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 3e5651E05C8
Action start 18:08:41: ProcessComponents.
MSI (s) (F4:78) [18:08:41:722]: 
Error 997.Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.
```

Comment: @jessehouwing well I was digging around the log file but I don't understand a lot of it and I did see a lot of errors in it but didn't know which one was causing everything.

Comment: @jessehouwing yes and i dont get "11.On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click String Value. Create String Values that contain the product codes (including braces {}) of the products that have to be added to the Safe Recipients list.

The NAME of the String Value is the "product code" and the VALUE can be left blank. To obtain the product code for other MSIs, open the MSI by using the ORCA tool that is available in Windows SDK."
this part i don't understand like what should i type in ?
also i don't have any of the updates that were said to be deleted in the blogpost.

Comment: @jessehouwing no idea what you just said.

Comment: @jessehouwing well i dont think it's that i mean everywhere i search it says delete KB updates but I don't have the suggested KB updates

Comment: now standart behavior? i'm confused

Comment: @jessehouwing can this be the problem ? https://imgur.com/T0jRKGl

Comment: @jessehouwing so is it repairable ?

Comment: @jessehouwing it's local and i created a new profile still the same error.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar Visual Studio install failure ("User cancelled" and "Overlapped I/O" messages) on Win 8.1 Pro.  I eventually found this thread:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2014/10/27/error-997-overlapped-i-o-operation-is-in-progress-kb2918614-breaks-windows-installer-service.aspx

After I renamed the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18 folder then the VS install worked fine.

Comment: Hotfix doesn't work for windows 10!  Just for Win 7, 8, 8.1

Answer (score 1):

It's almost impossible to "tell" you what's wrong or how to fix this. The error is coming from the fact that your crypto store is somehow corrupt. It happens sometimes, it's hard to say why. Last time I had these kind of issues I decided to do a fresh install of Windows 10 and that made all the problems go away. I ended up in that state because I updated the firmware of my laptop. Did not figure out exactly what went wrong, It doesn't take too long to do a fresh install, it takes longer to try and figure it out.

There are a few things that may help though, there are a few reasons this error may occur:

- Virus scanner is running and doing funny thing.
- You have a virus on your machine and it's doing funny things
- You're using a [mandatory or temporary Window Profile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2014/10/27/error-997-overlapped-i-o-operation-is-in-progress-kb2918614-breaks-windows-installer-service.aspx). Changing that to a normal profile should fix this issue.
- It is possible that some part of your Windows Installer database has been corrupted, [try running this Fit-It tool to see if that resolves the issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall).

If these things don't help, and you want to try something else, you can turn off the hash checks altogether **WARNING** this allows installation of corrupted MSI packages and is considered very insecure. Only do this as a last resort:

1. Create a DWORD named `SecureRepairPolicy` with value `1` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer`

Run the installation, which should succeed now and **after rebooting reset the flag to either its previous value or delete it if it didn't originally exist**.

If you need Microsoft support with this issue, [file a bug on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio) and be sure to attach the [Visual Studio installation log collection data that is gathered by this tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493).

**Note:** many forum posts and other topics mention the deinstallation of specific Windows Hotfixes. This was an option, though insecure, when this problem was not yet part of the default installation and was specifically triggered by the installation of the hotfix. With Windows 10 there is no hotfix to uninstall, as the stuff that is causing this issue has been installed with the clean operating installation and cannot be uninstalled.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

Solution that did it for me is: 
1. Go to Control Panel.
2. Go to User Accounts.
3. Make Changes to my account in PC settings.
4. Click Sign in with a local account (if you are logged with a microsoft account).
5. Sign in with the local account and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was almost the same. Just first time I was installing community version. and it failed. Maybe it happend because I lost my internet connection. And one of the packages were downloaded wrong. after that no mater If I tryed community  online installation or dream-spark community or Enterprise. It always failed.

So suggestion to delete *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18* folder worked just fine. I just didn't want to repeat installation, so I deleted it everywhere it was created.
After that tryed adding more features ant it worked without deleting S_1-5-18.

So thnx PaulM