# Unable to install visual studio 2015 and SSDT 2015.

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I am  getting the error when I try to install visual Studio and it says user cancelled I did not cancel the set up.

I have just upgraded to windows 10. Do I have to change anything in order to download the Visual studio 2015.

```
[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i000: MUX:  Watson Bucketting Parameters
[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i000: MUX:  P1 - vs_enterprise
[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i000: MUX:  P2 - 14.0.24720.00.00
[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i000: MUX:  P3 - 14.0.24720
[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i000: MUX:  P4 - Install
[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i000: MUX:  P5 - vs_communitycore
[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i000: MUX:  P6 - Install
[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i000: MUX:  P7 - 0x80070643
[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i000: MUX:  P8 - Error 997.Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.

[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i000: MUX:  P9 - 
[10F8:10E8][2016-01-05T01:29:49]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: Might be related to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2014/10/27/error-997-overlapped-i-o-operation-is-in-progress-kb2918614-breaks-windows-installer-service.aspx  Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840924/failed-visual-studio-2015-installation

Answer (score 0):

you need install the update of Microsoft visual C++ redistributable tools, only this update... open your control panel and search the update.