# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and Python 3.5 compiling errors

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2015, python-3.5

To preface this, I've been through every tutorial with regards to this problem and have not found a solution.

I am running Python 3.5, trying to compile Cython code for a numerical problem I have. I put `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc` into command line and I get the dreaded `unable to find vcvarsall.bat` error.

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Communitiy Edition, including all c++ options (like common tools) as well as the SDKs. I have uninstalled, reinstalled multiple times and slowly lost my mental faculties. I have searched the downloaded Visual Studio files and `vcvarsall.bat` returned no results.

When I download Visual Studio 2015, do I download all of it? Much of it seems irrelevant and I was under the impression that `vcvarsall.bat` comes with c++ common tools.

Failing all of this, is there an alternative compiler I can use for Python 3.5? I've read that MinGW is not an option, so if something else works I'd worship whoever pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you make sure vcvarsall.bat exists in your VS 2015 installation directory somewhere? Did you confirm your PATH environment variable correctly makes vcvarsall.bat accessible?

Comment: vcvarsall.bat does not exist, after running  search on my C: drive.

Comment: If you install VS Community 2015 with "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" selected, then along with everything else, vcvarsall.bat is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`. If it's not, then you may have some registry or file system cruft that's preventing the install from completing successfully. Check out answers like [Failed Visual Studio 2015 installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840924/failed-visual-studio-2015-installation) for solutions, or just do a web search.