# Visual Studio Community 2015, installation failed at Enable Graphics Tools

Tags: visual-studio

wonder if someone can help.
I am installing Visual Studio Community on Windows 10 Pro that's on Parallels Desktop for Business and it's doing my head in.
Installation is failing saying user cancelled installation.

I have noticed that it goes up to the point where t's trying to Enable Graphics Tools.
I have uploaded the log file if you guys can see and advice?

Thanks a bunch

Log File: http://www.filedropper.com/ddvscommunity20160504024220

Comment: The *relevant portion* of the log needs to be here, in your question itself. You can link to the full log, but the relevant significant portion needs to be here; if the off-site location is unavailable for some reason, your question has no value without that content.

Comment: you get the error **Error 997 Overlapped I/O operation is in progress** Look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31840924/1466046